# How to show an UIActivityIndicatorView whitin UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, uiactivityindicatorview

I'm beginner on iOS development and I have an issue about how to show an UIActivityIndicatorView.

This is my structure:

I have an UITabBarController as root VC.
Inside this TabBarController in first guide I have an UITableViewController
Inside TableView I do an REST requisition (at this moment, a fake requisition).

What I want?

When I launch the app, the TableView is loaded and the requisition is done.
While the requisition is made, I want to show the UIActivityIndicatorView.

My problem is show this ActivityIndicatorView :(

My code

**MainViewController (root VC)**

```
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UITabBarController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupTabBarItems()
}

private func setupTabBarItems() {

    let items: [String] = ["Home", "Carrinho", "Categorias", "Conta"]

    let homeVC = HomeTableViewController()
    let carrinhoVC = UIViewController()
    let categoriasVC = UIViewController()
    let contaVC = UIViewController()

    let tabBarList = [homeVC, carrinhoVC, categoriasVC, contaVC]

    for i in 0..<4 {
        tabBarList[i].tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: items[i], image: UIImage(named: items[i]), selectedImage: UIImage(named: items[i]))
    }

    viewControllers = tabBarList
}
}
```

**HomeTableViewController (table view)**

```
import UIKit

class HomeTableViewController: UITableViewController {

let progressView: UIActivityIndicatorView = {
    let p = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.whiteLarge)
    p.backgroundColor = .black
    p.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    p.startAnimating()
    return p
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // **the method is called here**
    setupIndicatorView()
    /* others methods */
}

private func setupIndicatorView() {
    guard let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow else {return}

    window.addSubview(progressView)
    window.bringSubview(toFront: progressView)

    // function to add constraints (is an extension of UIView)
    window.constraint(pattern: "H:|[v0]|", views: progressView)
    window.constraint(pattern: "V:|[v0]|", views: progressView)

}
/* other methods */
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the progressView directly to the tableView:

```
private func setupIndicatorView() {
    self.view.addSubview(progressView)
    progressView.center = self.view.center // or instead use autolayout if you prefer it
}
```